# What's the difference between $(command here) and `command here`

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In bash scripting what is the difference between $(command) and `command`. They both return the output of the command.

Let's say echo "There are $(wc -l < /etc/group) lines." and echo "There are `wc -l < /etc/group` lines.

They both print the same result.

Answer (score 0):

They are essentially the same thing, but the backtick method is deprecated I think, and the brackets method is preferred.

Both methods indicate command substitution though.

Comment: Roger that for next time!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot how the ` ` were called. My native language isn't english. But thanks. And thanks also, @Cyrus.